# module 'rasterio' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: rasterio

I am new to rasterio. I'm trying to open a tif file using this code:

```
import rasterio
dataset= rasterio.open('/home/zaianir/Documents/DB/serie_temporelle_s2/serie_temporelle_s2/Sentinel2_T31TCJ_MASKS.tif')
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'rasterio' has no attribute 'open'
```

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: Have you reviewed the `rasterio` documentation?  It looks like it does not have an `open` function.

Comment: I found it in the documentation of rasterio https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/reading.html

Comment: Rasterio does have an `open` function. Please double check your file path. Also make sure you have a good install of rasterio. Does `import rasterio` work? If these do not yield results, try a fresh install in a conda environment.

Comment: What versions of python, rasterio and pip are you using? What’s your OS?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error two weeks ago.
I installed rasterio 1.0.21 with conda (not with pypi).
Now, rasterio.open("_.tif") works.

Answer (score 0):

You first install anaconda navigator, then install required libraries by using conda install in conda prompt.